# Pure PHP/HTML views VS template engines views

Tags: html, templates, smarty, twig

I would like to know which approach is faster, using the pure PHP in the HTML files or using a template engines like Smarty,Twig, ... 
What I would particularly like to know is next: which is parsed faster, is the Smarty cache for example faster than using pure PHP? 
Which of the template engines is the fastest? I'm about to rewrite simple application where speed is on the first place.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

"Depends" is the answer to all your questions.

What is "faster"? Execution time? Development time? Maintenance? Memory overhead? A mixture of them? A template engine is usually trading in some performance (speed, memory) for better development and maintenance.

If you are talking about purely dynamic templating (meaning: template evaluated on every request) PHP will outrun any template engine. This is a nobrainer, really. If you're taking caching into account, a template engine like Smarty may help. Caching is nothing you couldn't implement yourself in plain PHP, though. With Smarty it's just been done for you (and on a far more sophisticated level than you possibly would).

If you are using a framework, say Symfony, it might be wise to use Twig, as Twig and Symfony are tightly integrated. Sure you can use Smarty or plain PHP. The question here is: is it practicable?

Caching makes sense when building sites from datasources like a database or remote APIs. What you are really saving (in a sense of reducing) here are database calls, intensive calculations, etc. Check if you have any time-intensive functions running to build your site. If so, use caching (if you can).

Knowing development/maintenance/convenience/performance trade-offs, I would (always) recommend using a template engine. Being a Smarty developer, I'll, of course, suggest using Smarty. That is unless you're using Symfony, then you might be better of with Twig. Or some other framework featuring some other template engine.

Please ignore posts like [Smarty vs. Twig](http://umumble.com/blogs/php/249/), as they only compare a very limited view of the engines. Don't trust benchmarks you haven't faked yourself™.

In general, though, Smarty 3.1 is a bit faster than Twig. Twig is doing a lot of stuff at runtime (being the time when a template is executed) that Smarty does on compile time (being the time when a template is prepared for execution). Twig is not really pissing away speed here. Twig needs to do certain stuff at runtime by design. They traded a bit of performance for a bit of "convenience" (Accessing arrays and objects with the same notation, for example).

Answer (score 14):

Let's tear the tropes related to this subject apart:

> **1.** Keep logic out of the presentation - Do not put 'code' into your HTML

Anyone who says this and then tells you to go with templating is contradictory:

- PHP is an *interpreted* language - it becomes C code on execution.
- The templating 'syntax' is *interpreted* into PHP

They must stop lying to themselves. Their 'templating syntax' *is* a programming language built on top of another, which in turn is built on top yet *another* language - That's inefficient, redundant, and *weird*.

Furthermore, I fail to see how the very existence of the *variables* every templating engine that ever was depends on aren't considered logic - Their existence, content and implementation depend on a *logical* backend.

And what of those templating systems with *if*/*else* statements and *for* loops? That's the very essence of logic - The very concepts which most *programming* languages utilize. They require *variable* data which can only be generated or exist through some form of computation.

**You cannot serve dynamic content without mixing presentation with logic. It's impossible.**

---

> **2.1** It's safer...

So, you don't **trust** your HTML guy?

**Case:** You think your HTML/CSS guy is stupid and will accidentally print the database password

If that's so, I've got news for you - Your environment is already not safe if sensitive data can be accessed/modified from anywhere within the program.

**Case:** You think your HTML guy will print random server constants - it's dangerous to allow him, as an individual, to work with server logic

I see - He's either stupid, or hates his job and wants to be fired and therefore will do something dumb like printing session variables. Fine, but to that I'll say...

...Why the heck is this stuff not **peer reviewed**? Even if he had no access to direct server logic but rather a fancy templating system, he could still equally spread his his stupidity/hatred merely because he has final say on output. Or, he could even be in cahoots with another programmer (If any) and still access server constants and co.

-

> **2.2.1** Good templating engines automatically sanitize output, or allow the templating-guy to do it himself - he knows better when data should be sanitized

You dummy.

You don't know when output should be sanitized? You couldn't do that yourself..?

Even so, maybe you're just the code monkey and the HTML guy is a web-security HTML-injection specialist, and *he* should be the one sanitizing output. In that case, giving him access to PHP also allows him to use the likes of `htmlspecialchars()` rather than whatever the template gives him to do the same thing.

Regarding automatic escaping, provided you're *safely* passing along content, you can implement such a simple feature within the code you're doing so.

--

> **2.2** ...and I can control what data is being worked with

Think about classes, functions, etc - You throw data in, they work with it, then you get a result. Typically they do not deal with outside data unless it is handed to them (Doing otherwise is unclear, dangerous and bad practice - Some constants aside). Through these same methods, you can pass on precisely what you need to your output in an efficient, clear and unlimited manor.

--

All that said, it seems like the reason you *think* your templating engine is any safer than plain code is because you're lacking in several areas of general *safety*:

- You (Or whoever) do not peer review content - You allow *individuals* to output content.
- You are not implementing proper or safe programming practices, and seem to not realize that you *can* control what's passed along from point **A** to **B**.

---

> **3.** PHP syntax is too hard/difficult to teach the style people

The truth is it's no more complicated than the psuedo-syntax created by template systems such as Smarty, so if this is an issue than dynamic content isn't for you.

The following is in PHP 'short syntax' - Is it too difficult?

`<div class='username'><?= $username ?></div>`

---

> **4.** It's too much work to develop my own solution

Though I'd argue it's not, you're free to choose whatever you wish! Choose whatever fits your needs best. They're usually free, not difficult to integrate, and come with loads of features out of the box.

---

---

I'm under the impression that most people opt for templating simply because it looks 'neater' within the file - They love thinking that the TPL file is some special thing they created, they like the way the syntax looks; As if by some magic, the variable is 'called' by the little `@` or `#` symbol and hops from your logic into the output.

It seems like a trick - The beautiful enchantress (*AKA The templating engine*) draws you in with her beauty. Though she's appealing to the eye, she's *really* a blood sucking demon and extracts your soul (*Server resources*) in exchange for eye candy nobody else sees (Your users would much rather have a faster website *and* more features funded by the $$$ you're saving on power/server renting)

```
<title>{{@title}}</title>
Vs
<title><?= $title ?></title>
```

---

---

I will admit, there's only one case I can think of in which templates have any ground over PHP - Portability to other applications. appartisan's answer addresses that. Even so, it's not hard to replace `<?= $var ?>` with `{{@var}}` - *That's* a job for a templating-esque system.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154562/discussion-between-vaxquis-and-super-cat).

Comment: I think, it is the best answer. Why we simply do not stick to the basics when there is actually not getting much extra benefits. When needed one can use: `htmlspecialchars()`. It should be alright. I Prefer raw php. Thanks to Super Cat.

Comment: This discussion may now be a bit obsolete. Nowadays I feel like the best split is to  have the "html" guy develop frontend applications, the "app"  guy the mobile app, and the backend guy to provide API's to support it all.  But let's take a short leap in time. The templating engines I worked with do actually compile the templates into plain PHP. Also, PHP extensions (twig, phalcon etc.) have been around for quite some time. The performance hit may not as all be as drastic as you make it sound. In my opinion templating engines have promoted best practice, separation of concerns and so forth...

Comment: I agree that decisions should be carefully considered. Neat code should not be the most important thing to think about. It is why I don't like Yaml for example, I would love to hear your opinion about that lol.   I do feel like this post is/was opiniated and did not do justice to what templates have offered the community.  Also, I hardly consider logic in the view layer the same as business logic. I feel like controller should NOT contain any notion of how the data is presented. A controller (in a perfect world) should not care much about whether it outputs HTML, Json or XML.

Comment: Templating engines have helped to promote this way of thinking. You can start looking at your template as a (extensible and flexible) presentation of your view. But you don't care what it is, how it looks, or what format it it will produce......... All you know is that this blackbox will produce the output you need.  Sure, all of this is possible with PHP, clean code is not dependent of any tools. But patterns and standards do help developers  to think alike. Also, the well known ones are often language agnostic and much easier to port than plain PHP nowadays.

Comment: @user1441149 Your input was better suited as a separate answer than a comment thread. I disagree, and at worst your issues are mediated by having your interpreter in a different application parse PHP. The "template guy" doesn't even need to know they're working in PHP, nor is there any requirement for separate syntax. Useless abstraction, for the sake of some imaginary standard. This was was also an answer to runtime-templating engines, not templating software that generates PHP. That still aligns with my answer.

Comment: And to fit in the last bit - the answer addresses many of the concerns presented, and points out the flaws pure-PHP "templating" imposes. So again, to emphasize, recap: I don't care if your program has templates. This is not an attack on people. PHP has its issues here - non portable (sort of/normally - your other application could be made to parse the PHP-code, or the underlying PHP code could be altered to reproduce in the new-templating style). Points still stand, your internal standards are yours, not everybody's, and great - both solutions produce awesome results. Do what works for you.

Comment: *"That's inefficient, redundant, and weird"* I have to disagree. You could say "it's all code" so put it all in one file. Or start with some SoC and have a few separate files like header, footer, etc. This is where good code design has originated, to the point we have really good SoC, then SRP and such come naturally making code much easier to work with and maintain. Separating view into a templating layer away from PHP is just another good approach to this. Of course, not if you have a 10 page website with barely any functionality.

Comment: @James sorry to have missed your comment for so long. Over time I've come to agree with more of the external views on the topic. Still, I have to disagree with roping the entire quote in there ("... _inefficient, redundant, and weird_ ") - it is certainly inefficient and redundant in some ways, and perhaps weird by the way some have valiantly fought for it (it was prior research and discussions found that prompted this answer of mine - there's some nonsense out there). This answer is more or less a foil, so do as you need.

Comment: I think this answer still holds up. There is so much hype and misinformation regarding frameworks. Many who flock to popular frameworks do so with the misconception that using them is the best and only acceptable way to develop applications. This leads to further propagation of misinformation and hype. I am not opposed to frameworks, some of them are truly amazing, but I see that many are unaware of the trade offs. Very simple solutions are possible that can provide most of the desirable functionality with similar design structures and considerably less processing power.  <?= $pretty;?>

Answer (score 6):

Simply and purely opinion, I think the only advantage is portability. You can re-use templates or views from a template engine into other backend application. Say you're moving your application from PHP to Java, you don't need to refactor the templates.

Otherwise, you're adding complexity, adding other layer of execution ( more time ), more requirements to maintain the application ( you need people that knows that template engine ), and so on. PHP itself it's the best and more featured template engine you're going to get, probably the fastest, and you can do caching also, with the advantage of controlling cache from the backend application, and not from the view.

Answer (score 5):

I will take up this again as things have changed significantly and there are some pieces of evidence missing from the earlier answer.

Without getting deep into why frameworks use template engines over PHP which most do. For some reason there is a constant effort to "fix" PHP with another abstraction layer. Always with claims of simplicity without loss of versatility or performance.

Regardless, the use of PHP is still the fastest and most versatile way of templating. PHP in it's [earliest incarnations](http://php.net/manual/en/history.php.php) looked much like a templating language. But let's take a look at the advancements in PHP and place them side by side with [the after layers](http://www.sitecrafting.com/blog/top-5-php-template-engines/).

Twig and some others claim caching something which was always an addon in earlier versions of PHP. Caching is now a [default part of PHP5.5+](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.opcache.php) (Opcache) and so using PHP as a template language will give more performance enhancements.

Twig and others claim simple syntax for designers. In comparing the [syntax of a template engine](https://www.drupal.org/node/1918824) you'll see that the logic is similar with the only benefit of using a template system like Twig being another layer of security separation between the designer and the underlying system code.

Two very popular CMS Wordpress and Drupal used PHP as their template engines. So the old argument of using a template engine to secure and simplify the use of PHP while designing a website is not really valid in today's web. While Drupal 8 is moving on to Twig it mostly because twig is part of Symfony Framework ( returning to why do frameworks use template engines). Wordpress on the other hand is still using PHP. As Wordpress is growing by leaps and bounds with web designers using PHP to help this happen. Drupals Community has also been split in part by decisions to use Twig and Symfony.

So it would seem that using PHP is the better choice in terms of performance but also the preference for themers and designers going forward. At least all evidence leads to this conclusion.

That being said here's my baseless opinion. I think that using anything other than PHP as template engine in today's web covers some inherent weaknesses in the underlying framework or web application architecture. That weakness being its [complexities and complications](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/PHP.html) that cannot be explained easily at the designer or themer level.

If you are writing a lightweight application that has to be small. Keep it small and performing optimally by using PHP and leave the other engines to "enterprise" level groups and projects

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem with the argument that logic and data display must be separared as much as possible. I found that data validation and display actually requires a lot of logic on forms. Information about data type, number range, relation between different data requires a lot of code. The real question is should we use a template language on the server side or Javascript on the client side. By using Ajax and client side code for data display and validation, I end up having very little template code. The biggest problem with template engines is the intoduction of new code rules and syntax. I see the future with PHP, Jquery and Ajax and template engines loosing its appeal.