# Using template engine twig in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, twig

I wonder if it is optimal to use a template engine with Cakephp 2.x like Symfony2 does. I have read that there are several template engines like [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) and [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit another question ["Pure PHP/HTML views VS template engines views"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363215/pure-php-html-views-vs-template-engines-views) for some insight into the templating engine vs php topic.

However, since you reference CakePHP, I would recommend against using a templating engine unless you require it. In my opinion, if you can markup a page in Twig or Smarty, you should be able to code a view page in CakePHP.

A big benefit of some templating engines is the built in caching functionality but you can get much greater flexibility by using [CacheHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/cache.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have integrate them Here is my code

> ```
> function generate_reports(){
>         echo Configure::version();
>         $this->autoRender = false;
>
>         include('../vendors/Twig/autoload.php');
>         $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('../views/reports/templates');   
>         // $array=array('index' => 'Hello {{ name }}!');
>         //$loader = new Twig_Loader_Array($array);
>         $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
>         echo $twig->render('index.html', array('name' => 'Fabien'));
>      }
> ```

I have download  twig and put inside the vendors folder

then i have create folder named templates inside the views folder
create file index.html 
this is content of  index.html file --> Hello {{ name }}!